# Make communication between 2 android phones over BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have two android smartphones (Xperia Z and Xperia Z1) and both have BLE capability.

Can I connect to one of them as a peripheral over BLE? In my application I can see and connect a BLE as peripheral (CC2541 device) and I can see all services and characteristics. 
But same application can not see one of my phones??

Is there a way to achieve that??

Comment: One of my phones? Which one?

Comment: It does not matter. I have my app on my two phones and i can see CC2541 deivce from either. But I cant see one of the phone.

Comment: Or can I advertise from my android phone to make my phone peripheral??

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 4.4 there is no support for peripheral mod in the Android BLE apis.  You would need this to be able to make two phones talk over BLE setting one up as a peripheral and the other as central.

There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59693) for the feature you may want to take notice of.

If you just want to be able to get the two phones connecting there is nothing stopping you from using classic Bluetooth which should be perfectly workable.

Comment: Thanx for your help. I noticed it what you mentioned about. And this is an official video and screenshot
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326240948
http://imgur.com/AqIRJ7q

Answer (score 1):

Android does not support peripheral mode till version 5.0(latest version)  therefore you can not communicate with two smartphone over BLE.

You can communicate over BLE with sensor device and smart phone here smartphone app works as client and senser device as a server.

and if you want to communicate between two smartphone you have to use classic bluetooth.