# Bluetooth Low Energy code is not scanning devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My code for scanning devices in Bluetooth LE scenario is not working. It is running fine without any exception or error. But onLeScan() function (in leScanCallback) is not calling at all while other Bluetooth Low Energy device is in vicinity...

```
public class ScanBle extends Activity {

    private BluetoothAdapter myAdapter;
    private Handler bleHandler;
    private long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> allBleDevice;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdaptor;
    private String TagBle = "ScanBle";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BluetoothManager bm = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        myAdapter = bm.getAdapter();
        listAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_scan_ble);
        allBleDevice = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        bleHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if(myAdapter == null || !myAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBt = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBt);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Le Feature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        startScan(true);

        if(listAdaptor.getCount()>0)
        {
            ListView lv = new ListView(this);
            lv.setAdapter(listAdaptor);
            setContentView(lv);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Ble devices Found Bazingaaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }   

    public void startScan(final boolean enable) {

        Log.d(TagBle , "startScan() started");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(enable)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scan is running...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            bleHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myAdapter.stopLeScan(callbackBle);
                }

            }, SCAN_PERIOD );
            myAdapter.startLeScan(callbackBle);

        }
        else
        {
            myAdapter.stopLeScan(callbackBle);
        }
    }


    public BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callbackBle = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TagBle , "callBackBle() Running");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    BluetoothDevice tempDevice = device;
                    allBleDevice.add(tempDevice);
                    listAdaptor.add(tempDevice.getName()+"\n"+tempDevice.getAddress());
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your Logcat output?

Comment: Thanks for Response... I got an answer. Actually i have two android devices and i was trying to scan one by another, which can't possible as android device works as BLE central and central can only talk to peripheral in BLE scenario. Ofcourse my code will work if i will put some peripheral in the vicinity of my device. Answer is here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799280/make-communication-between-2-android-phones-over-ble

Comment: Ok. Than its done. Maybe Android 5 will provide you the possibilty to do what you want, as it introduces Peripheral mode to android